# Establish a shared terminal between two PCs through the internet

Tags: ssh, remote, internet

My PC and that of my friend are in two different local networks, each connected to the internet via a router, each LAN has only one IP which is temporallily allocated by the ISP. What problems do we have to overcome in order to establish a situation in which each of us can see the other's terminal and typing on our PC?

In addition to mentioning the obstacles, what terms would you suggest to look up that deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around the temporary IP address allocation, you'll want to look at dynamic DNS. Find a domain registrar that supports dynamic DNS, then each of you register a domain name and follow the registrar's instructions for setting up automatic updates of your IP address. This will allow you to connect to your friend's computer (or vice-versa) without having to worry about the IP address expiring, since the domain name will always point to the currently-assigned address.

On the LAN side, each of you will need to set your PC to a static internal IP address if you haven't already. The details of how to do so depend on what distro you're using. As an example, my router's internal IP address is 192.168.1.1, and it assigns addresses in the range 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.199 to DHCP clients on my home network. On my Debian PC, which I want to be able to access from outside the LAN, I set up my primary ethernet adapter in `/etc/network/interfaces` with a static address outside of the router's DHCP range, like so:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Then, in the router's firewall settings, I turned on port forwarding for TCP port 22 (the default SSH port) to internal address 192.168.1.10 (my computer's static address).

Before you expose that port to the world, take care of a few steps to mitigate against SSH attacks:

- Do not allow root login in SSH. (`PermitRootLogin no` in your sshd configuration file.)
- Allow connections only for a particular (non-root, and otherwise unprivileged) user. (`AllowUsers my_user_id your_user_id` in your sshd configuration file.) For this, you can specify your own user ID and your friend's, or create a separate user account specifically for the purpose. The important thing is that you don't allow connections from user IDs that commonly get created by major packages (e.g., mysql, www-data) that may have default passwords. Those are easy targets for script kiddies.
- Use a strong password on the accounts that are whitelisted in the above step.
- Alternately, look at `ssh-keygen` to avoid having to use a password once both systems have authenticated with each other.
- Install some software that blocks connection requests from a given remote host after some number of failures. I'm using fail2ban for this purpose, and it works well.

Now you should be able to connect to each other's computer, which just leaves you with the requirement of sharing a terminal. That's where [GNU Screen](http://aperiodic.net/screen/start) comes in. Whoever is hosting the session just needs to launch a terminal, start up screen, and enable multiuser so the other person can join the session. (See screen's man page for details on enabling multiuser.) After that, either or both of you can disconnect without killing the screen session, and reconnect to it at any later time. Even if the ISP changes your IP address (for either of you), thus killing your connection, you can still re-connect after the DNS entry is refreshed and join the same session again.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a reason why you need to achieve this, so my answer may not have the solution you need. But the simplest way to share a terminal with another user is to use [tmate](http://tmate.io/), which is a fork of tmux.

Tmate allows you to initiate a session (open your terminal and start tmate), which will provide you with 2x connection strings; a read an write (where the other person can type in commands) or read only (the other person can only see what you type).

The advantages is that once you have tmate installed on the server machine, you don't need to open any ports or install a VPN. The disadvantage is that the install is not very simple (not too complicated as well), and I don't thin you can transfer files.

Here's a quick demo video of tmate in action - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=is_VpIx3Z4M